# More on broken packages

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to get an Epson X19 scanner working.
First, I downloaded  their driver package for 20.04 LTS.
This broke because apt-get update returned errors because of a
google earth repository gone missing and an eoan archive.  I
eliminated these from the source list.  The install seemed
to work.

I tried this:

```
# apt-get install sane sane-utils libsane xsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsane is already the newest version (1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2).
libsane set to manually installed.
sane-utils is already the newest version (1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sane : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 xsane : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As suggested in answers to similar questions, I ran the standard apt commands to find and fix dependencies.  None were found to fix.  I uninstalled the Epson driver package and repeated the experiment with the same results.

These came up empty:

```
# dpkg -l | grep ^..r
# apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
# dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E ^.[^nci]
#
```

I tried uninstalling Gimp, which was installed by SNAP. That worked.  Now trying to reinstall through apt-get t hits the same error.

Since various utilities have been unable to identify a currently broken package,
I have to ask:  Is there a flag set in some file under /etc that marks me forever
for the sin of having held a broken package?

Comment: Best practice is to read your output: Your previous attempts should have clearly stated that `libsane` and `sane-utils` were already installed. You should have modified your next attempt accordingly.

Comment: Removing a Snap package should have indeed made no difference. Apt cannot see Snaps and does not care about any Snaps that are installed.

Comment: The *easy* way to identify a broken package is to try to install one of the broken dependencies. In this case: `sudo apt install libgimp2.0`. The output will either tell you the actual problem or lead you to another broken dependency (try installing that one).

Comment: Never mix sources from another distro or version.  This is a recipe for breaking your packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I'm still working on it.  After posting the question, I started following the chain of dependencies  libgimp2.0 -->  libgegl-0.4 --l> 2.0--> ibopenexr23, which is not

Comment: I'm still working on it.  After posting the question, I started following the chain of dependencies  libgimp2.0 -->  libgegl-0.4 --> iibopenexr23, which is not installable because the current version is libopenexr24.    WTF?  My next steps are to notify Ubuntu and to try to build a refreshed libgimp2.0 myself.

Comment: The mixing of different versions of Ubuntu wasn't my doing.  The machine this is happening on  is a 2 year old laptop (How time flies!) that initially had 18.04, 19.10 for a few hours because it failed to upgrade to 20.04 directly, and 20.04 since then.  Any weirdness is due to bugs/lags in the version upgrade process.